# You need a shiboken-based type

Tags: python, pyqt4, pyside, maya

When i run the code i get the following error line 11: You need a shiboken-based type. Not sure what i am doing wrong here . When i run just the GetMayaWindow() its runs properly but when run it in **init** its gives me error

```
import shiboken
from PySide import QtGui
import maya.OpenMayaUI as apiUI
from cStringIO import StringIO
import pysideuic
import xml.etree.ElementTree as xml

def GetMayaWindow():
    ptr = apiUI.MQtUtil.mainWindow()
    if ptr is not None:
        return shiboken.wrapInstance(long(ptr),QtGui.QMainWindow)

def LoadUiType(ui_file):
    parsed = xml.parse(ui_file)
    widget_class = parsed.find('widget').get('class')
    form_class = parsed.find('class').text
    with open(ui_file,'r') as f:
        o = StringIO()
        frame = {}

        pysideuic.compileUi(f,o,indent = 0)
        pyc = compile(o.getvalue(),'<string>','exec')
        exec pyc in frame

        form_class = frame ['Ui_{0}'.format(form_class)]
        base_class = eval('QtGui.{0}'.format(widget_class))

    return form_class,base_class

import shiboken
from PyQt4 import QtGui,QtCore,uic
from pymel.core import *
import pymel.core as pm
from pymel import *

ui_file = "D:/Swapnil/Workspace/R&D/modellingTools/ModellingTools.ui"
list_form,list_base = LoadUiType(ui_file)

class ModellingToolsUI(list_form,list_base):
    def __init__(self, parent =GetMayaWindow()):
        self.window_name = 'modellingTools'

        if window(self.window_name,exists = True ):
            deleteUI (seld.window_name)

        super(ModellingToolsUI,self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)


def run_plugin():
    ex = ModellingToolsUI()
    ex.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot mix PySide and PyQt classes/objects.

The `QtGui` module gets imported *twice*, so `sys.modules` will contain an entry for both `PySide.QtGui` *and* `PyQt4.QtGui`. But since `sys.modules` is a `dict`, python cannot guarantee which one you will get when you reference `QtGui` later on.

In your case, it's obvious that `QtGui.QMainWindow` is actually a `PyQt4` class, which is why you get that error.