# Maya Python - "You need a shiboken-based type" Error

Tags: python, maya, pyside2, qtgui, shiboken2

Many Python based tools in Maya are now returning an error that is new to me.
"*You need a shiboken-based type. #*"

Very fresh to Python, so I don't really know what the issue is.
After looking around a bit a figured out it's maybe a conflict of definitions

The "*QtGui*" module is probably being imported more than one times, creating said conflict.
Not entirely sure that's the main cause, but it's the main suspect for now.

Now to be honest, I have just now started noticing that some of Maya's Python tools are not functioning because of this (like the "Type" creation tool), meaning that I have installed/uninstalled several python packages using *pip* before coming across the issue. I have no clue which package could be causing the conflict.

Are there any usual suspects that can cause this conflict?
I tried uninstalling some of the more recent packages but with no luck.

I also wouldn't want to damage anything else by individually removing packages until I find it.

These are the packages installed:

•       aenum       2.2.3
•       altgraph        0.10.2
•       appdirs     1.4.3
•       bdist-mpkg      0.5.0
•       blinker     1.4
•       bonjour-py      0.3
•       docutils        0.16
•       macholib        1.5.1
•       matplotlib      1.3.1
•       modulegraph     0.10.4
•       nine        1.1.0
•       nose        1.3.7
•       numpy       1.8.0rc1
•       pip     20.0.2
•       ply     3.11
•       ptvsd       4.3.2
•       py2app      0.7.3
•       PyFlow      2.0.1
•       pyobjc-core     2.5.1
•       pyobjc-framework-Accounts       2.5.1
•       pyobjc-framework-AddressBook        2.5.1
•       pyobjc-framework-AppleScriptKit     2.5.1
•       pyobjc-framework-AppleScriptObjC        2.5.1
•       pyobjc-framework-Automator      2.5.1
•       pyobjc-framework-CFNetwork      2.5.1
•       pyobjc-framework-Cocoa      2.5.1
•       pyobjc-framework-Collaboration      2.5.1
•       pyobjc-framework-CoreData       2.5.1
•       pyobjc-framework-CoreLocation       2.5.1
•       pyobjc-framework-CoreText       2.5.1
•       pyobjc-framework-DictionaryServices     2.5.1
•       pyobjc-framework-EventKit       2.5.1
•       pyobjc-framework-ExceptionHandling      2.5.1
•       pyobjc-framework-FSEvents       2.5.1
•       pyobjc-framework-InputMethodKit     2.5.1
•       pyobjc-framework-InstallerPlugins       2.5.1
•       pyobjc-framework-InstantMessage     2.5.1
•       pyobjc-framework-LatentSemanticMapping      2.5.1
•       pyobjc-framework-LaunchServices     2.5.1
•       pyobjc-framework-Message        2.5.1
•       pyobjc-framework-OpenDirectory      2.5.1
•       pyobjc-framework-PreferencePanes        2.5.1
•       pyobjc-framework-PubSub     2.5.1
•       pyobjc-framework-QTKit      2.5.1
•       pyobjc-framework-Quartz     2.5.1
•       pyobjc-framework-ScreenSaver        2.5.1
•       pyobjc-framework-ScriptingBridge         2.5.1
•       pyobjc-framework-SearchKit      2.5.1
•       pyobjc-framework-ServiceManagement      2.5.1
•       pyobjc-framework-Social     2.5.1
•       pyobjc-framework-SyncServices       2.5.1
•       pyobjc-framework-SystemConfiguration        2.5.1
•       pyobjc-framework-WebKit     2.5.1
•       Pyomo       5.6.8
•       pyOpenSSL       0.13.1
•       pyparsing       2.0.1
•       PyQt5       5.14.1
•       PyQt5-sip       12.7.1
•       PySide2     5.14.1
•       python-dateutil     1.5
•       pytz        2013.7
•       PyUtilib        5.7.3
•       Qt.py       1.2.4
•       qtwidgets       0.11
•       scipy       0.13.0b1
•       setuptools      18.5
•       setuptools      28.8.0
•       shiboken2       5.14.1
•       six     1.14.0
•       six     1.4.1
•       vboxapi     1.0
•       xattr       0.6.4
•       zope.interface      4.1.1

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT - 12/3/2020 20:30**

As an example for when this error occurs, I'm also including this script from PyFlow:

```
import ptvsd
from maya import OpenMayaUI as omui
from shiboken2 import wrapInstance
from PyFlow.App import PyFlow
from PySide2.QtWidgets import QWidget

try:
    long  # Python 2
except NameError:
    long = int  # Python 3path

ptvsd.enable_attach(address=('0.0.0.0', 3000), redirect_output=True)

mayaMainWindowPtr = omui.MQtUtil.mainWindow()
mayaMainWindow = wrapInstance(long(mayaMainWindowPtr), QWidget)

if PyFlow.appInstance is None:
    instance = PyFlow.instance(mayaMainWindow, "maya")
    instance.show()
```

"*PyFlow*" is a promising little tool for visual scripting, which is great for novices like myself. The issues didn't start when I first ran it, but it helped me notice the error that many other python-based tools in Maya were giving now as well.

If I attempt to run this for example:

"*# Error: TypeError: file  line 15: You need a shiboken-based type. #*"

Answer (score 1):

have you an example of script that import QT ui.
Which version of maya are you using also ?

are all your imports look like this :

```
from PySide2 import QtWidgets, QtGui, QtCore
import shiboken2
```

have you maybe mix PyQt and PySide with some "`import sip2`"

---EDIT---

```
from maya import OpenMayaUI as omui
from shiboken2 import wrapInstance
from PyFlow.App import PyFlow
import PySide2.QtWidgets as QtWidgets

mayaMainWindowPtr = omui.MQtUtil.mainWindow()
mayaMainWindow = wrapInstance(long(mayaMainWindowPtr), QtWidgets.QWidget)

if PyFlow.appInstance is None:
    instance = PyFlow().instance(mayaMainWindow, 'maya')
    instance.show()
```

Comment: I'm using Maya 2019.

I started noticing the issue when I tried to use a tool called "PyFlow". The repository had a Maya launcher so I decided to try it. That's when I got the Type error and then started noticing it on other Py-based tools in Maya. I'm going to add to the original post the script that gives this sort of error as an example. Again, the issue didn't start when I started using said tool, but it just made me realise that other Py-Tools were having the same issue all the sudden.

Comment: it is using Qt module, are you using Qt module in all your scripts ? It might be indeed some kind of bad mix between PyQt5 and PySide2 parenting widget to maya window

Comment: Also I see you did put a ticket, did you try shiboke2 on Mac, building a small ui ?

Comment: I have never made anything that required me to use Qt, PySide or Shiboken before. I'm still learning so I never made anything with a UI at all before. I tried removing PyQt5 packages with `pip uninstall PyQt5`, but that didn't help. The conflict persists. Also, sorry, not sure what you mean by "ticket".

Comment: in order to parent PySide or PyQt to maya window, two different module are used :
sip for PyQt, shiboken with PySide. Qt is a wrapper by Marcus Ottosson that try to solve PySide, PyQt4, PySide2, PyQt5, by default it is supposed to use PySide2. Maybe somewhere in one script, you have a conflict between PyQt5, PySide2 and Qt parenting a window. You need to find any shiboken2 or sip2 in your scripts because a ui is fed with a non-shiboken object

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31117393/you-need-a-shiboken-based-type

Comment: Sorry, but by the time I saw your edit it was too late. I did a `pip freeze | xargs pip uninstall -y` to bleach all packages, clean everything up, and start reinstalling only the necessary modules. That fixed everything, but I regret not having the time for doing it incrementally so I can find the guilty package and warn others who might be reading. The remaining suspects were: 1-_appdirs_ 2-_nose_ 3-_ply_ 4-_Pyomo_ 5-_PyUtilib_ 6-_six_. One of these packages was causing the conflict.